# After javap -verbose, one constant pool item is missing

Tags: java, jvm

I create a Java class named JVMClassTest and then compiled. After that, I run "javap -verbose JVMClassTest".Where is the #4 of the constant pool.

```
    public class JVMClassTest {
        private int i = 0;
        private static String s = "tString";
        private final double d = 1.2d;

        public JVMClassTest() {

        }

        public int getI() {
            return i;
        }

        public static String getS() {
            return s;
        }

        public double getD() {
            return d;
        }
    }
```

Below is the screenshot of the result

[image]

Comment: Don't waste your time and our bandwidth by posting pictures of text here. Post the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [JVM specification on the classfile format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.5):

> The CONSTANT_Long_info and CONSTANT_Double_info represent 8-byte numeric (long and double) constants:
>
> ...
>
> **All 8-byte constants take up two entries in the constant_pool table of the class file.** If a CONSTANT_Long_info or CONSTANT_Double_info structure is the item in the constant_pool table at index n, then the next usable item in the pool is located at index n+2.